# Mid-bandwidth data and power over coax

Tags: fpga, serial, converter, coax

I am interested in transmitting both digital data and power over a single coaxial cable between two FPGAs. Communication should be at least half-duplex. Communication speed should be on the order of 50-100 Mbps (something like ECL might be required?). Power is coupled in via an inductor biasing network in the same way as some ["power over coax"](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla272/snla272.pdf?ts=1673724970563) GMSL SERDES pairs use. Here is a block diagram:

[image]

I'm looking for suggestions on how to fill in the black boxes, which take bi-directional IO to/from each FPGA and translate it into something capable of driving and receiving from a 50-ohm terminated (both end) coax that is biased with a voltage rail (power over coax; 12V in block diagram is an example anywhere from 5-12V is fine). I would like to use a minimum of parts. Data serialization, error detection, DC balancing, etc can take place inside the FPGA using e.g. [PonyLink](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/PonyLink) or something similar. I'm looking for the simplest and smallest translation scheme.

Why do I want to use a single coax? Because the circuit on the Vout side of the block diagram will be carried on a mouse's head for neural recording purposes. Any additional cabling is a mechanical hinderance to the animal. We are currently using a [DS90UB95x SERDES pair](https://www.ti.com/product/DS90UB953-Q1) and a 0.33mm OD microcoax which works well, but is power hungry. We want to reduce power consumption and size because we do not need the large data rates afforded by GMSL devices, which are meant for cameras typically.

Thanks.

Comment: Since the data rate is so low and a cable on a mouse is probably short I would be tempted to directly connect an IO pin to the cable with no active electronics. Perhaps a line driver if you didn't have an IO that could drive 50 ohms. That's as small as it gets.

Comment: What is the environment space in which the wire-attached rodent can wander around? Is the overall bulk of data the same in both directions for a long-term period? 50-100 Mbps is fairly high <-- is that data rate really necessary given that you say this: *we do not need the large data rates afforded by GMSL devices*?

Comment: I'd put a capacitor in series with each of theose 50 ohm termination resistors. There's no need to waste DC power heating them up!

Comment: @user1850479 The the cable can be several meters long. Maybe I should just go ahead and try driving the cable with the FPGA pin though, its an idea worth just trying.

Comment: @Andy The cable can be 2-3 meters long. The environment can up to 10 m^2. As you are implying, most data comes from the animal to the receiver (just like with the GMSL SERDES which have a high speed forward channel and low speed back channel). This is fine, just kind assumed a symmetric  solution might be the simplest.

Comment: @Andy re bandwidth: We have 100-200 electrodes sampled at 30kHz @ 16-bits per sample => 50-100 Mbps, which as you say is not low, but is not at the Gbps level provided by the integrated SERDES we are currently using. We really don't use the the full 16-bit depth though, so this could be reduced a bit. The data is also sparse so compression might be an option but would likely cut into our power and size budget significantly.

Comment: I think you should try simulating a single direction scenario (transmit and receive). That shouldn't be too hard to implement then, when that looks good, add the bits to make it bidirectional (also not too troublesome). A simulator will eat this problem and give you a really good basis for making modifications  and improvements from the comfort of your PC. A simple scrambling scheme for the data is easily implemented with a few D types and exors.

Comment: Go for a peak-to-peak data amplitude of about 1 volt and use a comparator for detection (possibly a MAX999). I might consider a balanced transmission and that means inductor power feeds and inductor power-take-offs on both wires. Having said that, it's coax so it shouldn't be a problem single ended.